# Why am I randomly getting a "There was no endpoint listening at" error?

Tags: .net, wcf, endpoint

I am using .NET to create a WCF and a website that calls it. About 5% of the time I get an error that says there was no endpoint listening. I don't know why it works most of the time but then sometimes it doesn't.

Here is the code I am using, I am not sure if it is the way I am creating the WCF. I added a reference to the version of the WCF on my machine but then if I am on production I change the endpoint address to the production url

```
Dim wcfService = New StagingService.Service1Client
            If Clng0(AppConfig("isProduction")) = 1 Then
                wcfService.Endpoint.Address = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress    
   ("http://www.myurl.com/Service1.svc")
          End If
```

Comment: What kind of machine is this service hosted on? How many connections are typically open? Could it be something like a server throttling issue (e.g. too many requests / sessions at the same time)?

Comment: The machine is running Windows Server 2003. The site doesn't get a whole lot of traffic, so I don't think that is the issue. I just looked back at my code to make sure I am closing all connections when I am done with them.

Is there a way to find out how many connections the server allows?

Comment: I got another issue in the middle of the night when there appears to have only been 1 user on the site, so I don't think it is a too many requests issue.